# Would be possible for Compiz to work on Windows?

Tags: windows, compiz

I obviously don't think it would work as it is. Its more like, does Windows internal architecture allows for some third party SW to integrate in between? From what I read about Compiz, I believe it creates its own window, and somehow mixes graphics from System X to its own. But it still has to catch events like EXIT button and so on.

Does Windows even allow this? Let 3rd program to scan for input of another window? And more, catching output of GUI and replace it?

Comment: I can't see how this could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Windows even allow this? Let 3rd
>   program to scan for input of another
>   window? And more, catching output of
>   GUI and replace it? Thanks.

It is certainly possible. See [WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) for an example. Just note that Windows "officially" does not support this, applications like WindowBlinds use API hooking, subclassing etc. to perform their deeds.

Comment: Yeah, it's difficult, and unsupported, but it *is* possible.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not natively allow it - it has its own compositor framework built in called DWM that does much of the same internal functionality as Compiz. However, glitzy graphics that are systemwide are reserved for the OS to perform, sadly. As other people mention, doing this as a 3rd-party app is going to be really hacky and difficult.

Answer (score 0):

API Hooking:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx

Also, look at:
http://yodm-3d.en.uptodown.com/

A free 'Compiz' for Windows.